# ml command in Stata adding a constant when told not to

Tags: max, stata, cox-regression

I'm trying to write a little program to do a Cox proportional hazard model with the eventual aim of being able to solve a problem none of the current programs can manage. I've come unstuck at the first hurdle though trying to reproduce the basic functionality of `stcox`. Using `stcox` to check it's working properly I can show that the likelihood is correct since the maximum is at the same location using `ml plot`. However from this point forward it breaks down. The variable `drug` takes values 1 or 0, and since it is a Cox model no constant can be fit so this is specified in the equation. However, by observing the *Xb* values each time the log-likelihood is calculated it can be seen that the values for both control and treatment arms are varying, in fact the difference between them is fixed and just a constant is varying.

```
clear all
webuse drugtr

*Show st settings
stset

*Fit Cox proportional hazards model
stcox drug, breslow 

gen timem = -_t
sort timem


capture program drop mlcox
program mlcox
version 10
args lnf Xb
tempvar risk sumrisk sumrisk2
qui gen double `risk'=exp(`Xb')
qui gen double `sumrisk'=0
local N=_N
forval j=1/`N' {
     qui replace `sumrisk'=`sumrisk' + exp(`Xb'[`j']) if _t[`j']>=_t
}
tab `Xb'
qui replace `lnf' = 0                       if $ML_y1==0
qui replace `lnf' = `Xb' - log(`sumrisk')   if $ML_y1==1
end

ml model lf mlcox ( died = drug, noconstant)
ml plot -4 1 30

ml maximize
```

Edit: Corrected the coding of the maximum likelihood, but still having problems with convergence.

Comment: There is complete code for the Cox model in <http://www.stata.com/bookstore/maximum-likelihood-estimation-stata/>, page 330-332

Comment: @ Buis: Can you please make sure the web site is correct?I got the error while opening the webpage.

Comment: http://www.stata.com/bookstore/maximum-likelihood-estimation-stata/

Comment: I've made corrections to the code now so it is certainly giving the correct maximum likelihood (ml plot shows this) but I am still failing to get ml maximise to search in the correct domain.